# Facebook GET Http Request

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like to ask a relative question to you. I say relative, because it is very hard for me and very easy for you.

I've tried and tried to make a live FB Feed on my site and here is the result:

When I entered;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageid}/feed?access_token={appid}|{appsecret}
```

I received the result I was looking for. However, it will sound so easy for you but, I don't know how to GET that array into a PHP variable.

I really need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can use the `file_get_contents()` function, so simply:

```
$results = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/{pageid}/feed?access_token={appid}|{appsecret}');
```

You may want to run the results through something like `$data = json_decode($results);`